# DB rebuild claiming changes that never actually change

Tags: php, database, silverstripe

I have quite a large DB in SilverStripe and occasionally I change it. Most of the time it works fine but depending on what changes I can get blue text usually in reference to constraints. In the past I've had to go in and manually drop either the table, constraint or temporary table. Now I've got another one on something I don't want to drop. Here is the message:

```
Field SiteTree.ClassName: changed to varchar(255) default 'SiteTree' check ("ClassName" in ('SiteTree', 'Page', 'HomePage', 'ErrorPage', 'RedirectorPage', 'VirtualPage')) (from varchar(255) default 'SiteTree' check ("ClassName" in ('SiteTree', 'Page', 'ErrorPage', 'RedirectorPage', 'VirtualPage', 'VirtualPageTest_VirtualPageSub', 'CMSMainTest_ClassA', 'CMSMainTest_ClassB', 'CMSMainTest_NotRoot', 'CMSMainTest_HiddenClass', 'ContentControllerTest_Page', 'ContentControllerTestPageWithoutController', 'ContentControllerTestPage', 'SiteTreeActionsTest_Page', 'SiteTreeTest_PageNode', 'SiteTreeTest_Conflicted', 'SiteTreeTest_ClassA', 'SiteTreeTest_ClassB', 'SiteTreeTest_ClassC', 'SiteTreeTest_ClassCext', 'SiteTreeTest_ClassD', 'SiteTreeTest_ClassE', 'SiteTreeTest_NotRoot', 'VirtualPageTest_ClassA', 'VirtualPageTest_ClassB', 'VirtualPageTest_ClassC', 'VirtualPageTest_NotRoot', 'VirtualPageTest_PageWithAllowedChildren', 'SiteTreeTest_StageStatusInherit')))
```

This is the same for my Live and versions tables too.

My latest change to the DB doesn't have anything to do with page types. It also does complete the `dev/build` so a 500 error isn't causing the changes not to be applied.

Whats going on here and how can I get rid of this without dropping tables?

I should also add this is in a postgresql db.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: No matter how many times I rebuild it never goes away. It basically says it's applied but its not. Not sure if it will cause errors but it's annoying to always be there on a rebuild.

Comment: I suppose it's difficult for you to suggest how we could reproduce this?

Comment: Yeah, it's not really reliable with the page types as I didn't change anything to do with it. If you create a dbobject enum with 123 and then change it to 456 you might be able to reproduce it as that seems to always break it. I think as I can't find anything else online about it, it might be due to my postgres db.